# WordPress adding index.php to uploaded image URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm dealing with a client's site which is using WordPress 3.7.1. All the images on the site are working EXCEPT for the images in wp-content/uploads folder. The images files are in place and all paths are correct. From what I can tell, WordPress is inserting its index.php into the public URL for this image and it loads WP with a 404 page instead of the actual image. I can even copy and paste the provided URL from the Media section of WP and it still will not work.

Here is the default .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here is the attempted fix that I tried:

```
#My attempt at fixing the uploaded files issues
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```

The 2 lines above were pulled from a WordPress forum with similar issue however it has no affect on my site whatsoever. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is an example of non-working image URL and what it should be?

Comment: Something as simple as http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/FD_Awards2.jpg - which is what WP provides in the media gallery and is the public URL for the image, is not working. The directory is traversalable and there are no permission issues.

Comment: Does `/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/FD_Awards2.jpg` actually exist? Can you do `ls -l wp-content/uploads/2011/08/FD_Awards2.jpg`

Comment: Yes, the images files are listing in the directory and all paths are correct. When I go to that URL, I see a WordPress 404 page and not the image by itself.

Comment: Any other .htaccess files in your system (use `find` command to check)

Comment: The client has WordPress Super Cache on the site which I will disable to test. I suppose a better question is, how do I disable .htaccess from inserting index.php before wp-content/uploads?

Comment: Ad per rule shown above, it won't insert `index.php` for any valid file or directory. So if file is a valid image file then it should not happen.